# Swift - Change var with selectedIndex

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, delegates

I'm trying to go from a `ViewController1` to a `ViewController2` by changing the `selectedIndex` of the `tabBarController`.

In ViewController1:

```
func action() {
   _ = self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 4
}
```

In ViewController2:

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {
   var isOnInfo = true
}
```

My problem is pretty simple. I would like to change the value of `isOnInfo` in the `action()` function.
Is it possible?

Another way to do that would be to create a global var, but if I can avoid that it would be better.

Thank you for you answers.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend you to move your changing tabs logic in Tab bar controller.
Make your own class TabBarController(subclass of UITabBarController), set it as custom class of your tab bar controller at the storyBoard and move the function action() there.

```
import UIKit

class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func action(isOnInfo: Bool) {
        selectedIndex = 4
        if let viewControllers = self.viewControllers,
            let viewController2 = viewControllers[selectedIndex] as? ViewController2 {
            viewController2.isOnInfo = isOnInfo
        }
    }
}
```

Then in viewController1:

```
if let tabBarController = self.tabBarController as? TabBarController {
        tabBarController.action(isOnInfo: false)
    }
```

Comment: I tried but it's not working. The value of viewController2.isOnInfo is not changed...

Comment: strangely. I have created a project with it and it works for me. How many  view controllers does your tab bar have?

Comment: @KevinB Possible problems: 1) If you can not assign self.tabBarController as? TabBarController then you should assign TabBarController to yours at StoryBoard 2) If you can not assign viewController as? ViewController2 then you should check your selectedIndex. SelectedIndex starts from 0!  For example if you wanna set second viewController of 2 then selectedIndex = 1

Answer (score 0):

You can get object of viewcontroller at selected index in tabbarcontroller. once  you have it, you can modify any public property.

```
     func action() { 

   _ = self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 4

     if let vc2  = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers![4]  as?  
     ViewController2
               {

                   vc2.isOnInfo = true  
               }
    }
```